# Material UI button moves down when textField error message shown

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have added the material ui error message display to my text field, if I click on the button without any text typed on the text field, an error message will be shown, this message will push down the button, I want to stop that, I am unable to find the way to do that

This is my form code.

```
                            <Grid container  justify='center' alignContent='center'  >
                                <Grid item xs={12}   >

                                    <TextField

                                        id="outlined-full-width"
                                        label="Input"
                                        style={{  width:'100%',marginTop:30 }}
                                        placeholder="Add A Todo Item "

                                        margin="normal"

                                        InputLabelProps={{
                                            shrink: true,
                                        }}

                                        error={this.state.errorState }
                                        helperText={
                                            this.state.errorState && "Item name can't be blank"


                                        }
                                        size="large"
                                        variant="outlined"
                                        value={newItem}
                                        onChange={handleInput}




                                    />

                                </Grid>

                            </Grid>
                            <CardActions>
                            <Grid container  justify='center' alignContent='center'  >
                                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}  >

                                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    color='inherit'
                    fontsize='inherit'
                    style={styles.add}
                    startIcon={<AddIcon/>}

                >
                    Add Item
                </Button>

                                </Grid>

                            </Grid>

                            </CardActions>




                            </form>
```

Comment: In order to help you please post your entire code. How does the `errorState` get's set and everything

Answer (score 3):

In your main theme, add these rules so that the helperText / error text stays within the margin of your field. This will prevent the text from pushing down the content underneath.

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  // ...
  MuiFormHelperText: {
    root: {
      // Use existing space / prevents shifting content below field
      marginTop: 0,
      height: 0,
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: The `height: 0` prop did help me, thanks.

Comment: I don't know if its's because of the version but for me I had to use `createTheme({components: {MuiFormHelperText: {styleOverrides: {root: {//styles}}}})`